# How is 'key=lambda x: x[1]' working here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am sorting a tuple of tuples by second item. The tuple I need to sort is this: **tuple1 = (('a', 23),('b', 37),('c', 11), ('d',29)).** The solution to this program given on the internet is as follows:

```
tuple1 = (('a', 23),('b', 37),('c', 11), ('d',29))

print(tuple(sorted(list(tuple1), key=lambda x: x[1])))
```

What I can't understand is the function of **key=lambda x: x[1]** expression in the code. What does the keyword **key** denote here? I know lambda is an anonymous function. But how is it working in this code to give the desired output?

Comment: As a side note, you can use tuple1 rather than list(tuple1) in the expression since sorted takes any iterable.

Comment: hello, I tried it that way but didn't work

Comment: @CS2020--you tried `print(tuple(sorted(tuple1, key=lambda x: x[1])))`?  The results should be identical to using the code in your post.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword `key` is an argument to `sorted`, it is the element that is compared when sorting `list(tuple1)`

The lambda function simply selects the second element of each tuple in the list, so we're comparing the ints not the characters

Answer (score 2):

The `key` argument is ment to specify how to perform the sort. You can refer to the following link:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp

For a more in-depth explanation of `sorted` and it's arguments have a look at the following link:

https://developers.google.com/edu/python/sorting

In your case, you sort the list of tuples based on the second element from each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

For a List of T, key takes a function T -> int (or anything thats sortable, but ints behave in the most expected way), and sorts by those. Here T = (int, int) and the lambda returns the 2nd int